# Async function does not wait for Promise when called in another function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an async function that waits for a promise:

```
const getUserByImportMail = async (mail) => {
  const mailResult = await client.request(GET_COMPANY_BY_IMPORT_MAIL, mail)

  console.log("In file 1: " + inspect(mailResult))

  return mailResult
}
```

and another function in another file which does some checks on it:

```
const isSenderValid = mail => {
  const importMail = getUserByImportMail({importMail: mail})

  console.log("In file 2: " + inspect(importMail))

  // some checks
  return importMail
}
```

I always thought that async functions will wait for the Promise to resolve which they do, kinda:

```
// In file 1: { companies: [{obj}] }
```

but

```
// In file 2: Promise { <pending> }
```

Why is execution continued for `isSenderValid` and not being wait for the Promise to resolve, and how to fix it?

Comment: because there is no await

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `async` functions always return a Promise - the keyword works like a kind of a wrapper for a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getUserByImportMail` function is async, that means it will return a `Promise` for whatever it finally returns as `mailResult`. You should make `isSenderValid` also an `async` function and then it can `await` the result of the call:

```
const isSenderValid = async mail => {
  const importMail = await getUserByImportMail({importMail: mail})

  console.log("In file 2: " + inspect(importMail))

  // some checks
  return importMail
}
```

Then of course whatever calls `isSenderValid` also has to use `await` and be an `async` function itself. All the way down.

Alternatively `isSenderValid` can use the `Promise` directly, but in that case it cannot return `importMail`. If you call a function that is `async` i.e. returns `Promise` then you cannot return anything that depends on the result of that Promise directly: everything else has to be `async` as well.

Here's how you could handle the `Promise` inside `isSenderValid` and return another `Promise` which will resolve to `importMail`:

```
const isSenderValid = mail => {
  return getUserByImportMail({importMail: mail})
  .then(importMail => {
      console.log("In file 2: " + inspect(importMail))

      // some checks
      return importMail
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on this statement: `Alternatively isSenderValid can use the Promise directly, but in that case it cannot return importMail`?

Comment: He means you can do -> `isSenderValid.then(result => ....)`   Basically the callback version of Promises, and of course you can't return from a callback either.  IOW: Once `async` always `async`, sound limiting, but in the long run it's a good thing.. :)

Comment: Sure, was just in the process of updating my answer to include the Promise example anyway.

Comment: Very helpful. So essentially every function referencing a return value of a Promise will either need an await too or then.